# To detect service idle

Tags: c#

How to programmatically detect either my Apache webserver is idle using C#?
I already have an open source program that monitors mouse movement. But how can I monitor either the targeted server is idle/up/down?

Comment: Window messages are sent to _windows_.  A server is not a window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to have some target pages and then make some web requests and look for some target text (e.g. "Welcome to MySite" on those pages.

This will only tell you if it's up or down, not if it's idle.